# Footer not working properly when using jQuery Mobile and bootstrap together

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here is link :

https://jsfiddle.net/Beginner_at_programming/73n4ez7q/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <title>F-CropSap</title>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">

            <h1>jQuery Mobile</h1>

        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" align="center">
                    <div> <h5 align="center" id="headlabel">  </h5>  </div><br />

                    <div id="todoItems">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
           <h1>jQuery Mobile</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

I am unable to find out which css part I have to comment to work this fine. I want my footer fixed at bottom. can anyone suggest what to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add position fixed property make the footer fixed

https://jsfiddle.net/73n4ez7q/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <title>F-CropSap</title>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">

            <h1>jQuery Mobile</h1>

        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" align="center">
                    <div> <h5 align="center" id="headlabel">  </h5>  </div><br />

                    <div id="todoItems">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" style="position:fixed;"> <!-- Edit -->
           <h1>jQuery Mobile</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: @beginneratprogramming could you make this answer as the accepted one? :)

Comment: @beginneratprogramming just tick the "correct symbol" next to the answer